# REGEXP_REPLACE replacement in Oracle 9i

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to use Jason Bennet's PL/SQL ExcelDocumentType code in oracle 9i. 
(http://www.jasonsdevelopercorner.com/?page_id=8)

At the moment I can't compile it because it uses `REGEXP_REPLACE` which is not in oracle 9i.

Can anyone suggest an Oracle 9i replacement expression for the following....

```
(LENGTH(REGEXP_REPLACE(p_header_string,'[^'||p_delimiter||']','')))+1;
```

thanks

Answer (score 5):

I've figured it out...

```
v_elem_cnt := (length(p_header_string) - length(replace(p_header_string, p_delimiter)))+1;
```

thanks all

Answer (score 0):

Even today, this has been incredibly helpful.

Click on the following link, Ctrl-C, Ctrl-V, F5 and nothing else, magic happens.

[REGEXP_REPLACE / REGEXP_LIKE for Oracle 9i](http://phil-sqltips.blogspot.com/2009/06/regexpreplace-regexplike-for-oracle-9i.html)

Thanks a lot Phil!